# Is Argentina buying JF-17 Block-3 aircraft from Pakistan/China?

Tags: military, aviation, pakistan

Is Argentina buying [JF-17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAC/PAC_JF-17_Thunder) aircraft?

- [Governo argentino reserva US$ 664 milhões para compra de caças JF-17 Thunder em 2022](https://www.aereo.jor.br/2021/09/17/governo-argentino-reserva-us-664-milhoes-para-compra-de-cacas-jf-17-thunder-em-2022/)

> According to the Aviacionline website, the draft budget for the fiscal year 2022, which includes a $664 million request for the acquisition of the JF-17 Thunder Block III fighter jets, was presented to the Argentine National Congress. [Google Translate]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anymore developments have happened since Sep 21, but then Reuters [reported](http://web.archive.org/web/20210922191235/https://www.reuters.com/world/americas/argentina-plans-spend-664-mln-fighter-jets-possibly-china-or-us-2021-09-21/) that the source of the planes that Argentina was looking for had not yet been decided:

> Argentina is looking at buying up to $664 million-worth of multipurpose fighter jets to safeguard its airspace, the Defense Ministry said in a statement on Tuesday.
>
> A source with knowledge of the negotiations told Reuters that planes from China, the United States, Russia, South Korea or Israel were being considered.
>
> The process "is in the technical-economic and financial evaluation stage of five alternatives," the ministry said in an official statement.

Comment: This is consistent with the article, which says *budget* has been put aside, not that the purchase had been agreed.

Comment: @Oddthinking: there were more definitive statements made by otherwise reputable source, Including Janes https://www.janes.com/defence-news/news-detail/argentina-allocates-jf-17-funding-in-latest-fighter-recapitalisation-twist "Announced on 15 September, the draft budget for fiscal year (FY) 2022 includes USD664 million towards the purchase of 12 JF-17 Thunder Block III jets (including USD20 million for infrastructure)." with no alternatives mentioned except in the past tense.

Comment: I think we are agreeing. There is a claim that a (draft) budget had money put aside for the purchase, but that is very different to actually buying anything, which remains undecided.

Comment: @Oddthinking: frankly quite a bit of that is probably disinformation, as the UK has been looking to block such sales, especially if they include any UK components. That realistically leaves a much shorter list... Even the JF-17 (at least the Pakistani version) is equipped with a British ejection seat, but apparently China has a version with a Chinese seat; furthermore, Argentina wants to assemble the jet locally, from parts https://www.aerotime.aero/28954-Fact-check-is-Argentina-Buying-Pakistani-JF-17-jets