# Is Iraq buying JF-17 Block-3 aircraft from Pakistan/China?

Tags: china, pakistan, iraq

Is Iraq buying [JF-17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAC/PAC_JF-17_Thunder) aircraft?

- [Iraq orders 12 JF-17 fighter jets from Pakistan](https://www.globalvillagespace.com/iraq-orders-12-jf-17-fighter-jets-from-pakistan/)

> In recent developments, Iraq has decided to purchase 12 JF-17 Thunder Block III fighter jets from Pakistan. According to reports, the defense deal was approved by both the Iraqi and Pakistani governments, and a formal agreement is expected to be signed in Islamabad next month. [...]
>
> It is worth mentioning that recently, Argentina and Nigeria both have placed orders for Pakistani JF-17 Block III fighters.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to doubt this claim ? Have you looked for other news reports about that event ?

Comment: @Evargalo: a reason might be that Argentina isn't as committed to JF-17 as that story claims: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/52400/is-argentina-buying-jf-17-block-3-aircraft-from-pakistan-china Nigeria did actually buy a few (actually shipped) with an option to buy more.

Comment: Pakistanese media report the sell : https://nation.com.pk/25-Sep-2021/iraq-to-buy-12-jf-17-thunder-jets-from-pakistan

Comment: @Evargalo, There are no independent sources who support this claim.

Comment: @Evargalo: the Pakistani press commonly puts out jingoistic stories that can't be verified from other sources. The article you link to also claims "Earlier Argentina has agreed to buy 12 fighter jets from pakistan." (Yeah, they failed to capitalize "pakistan", amusingly enough.)